# Display large data in birt report

Tags: eclipse, grid, birt

I have 1 table with 2 column . dynamically data binded to the table . I have 1000 of records I am displaying 40 rows in each page sets Page Break interval = 40 . it takes 25 pages to displaying all records

ex:
[display data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmeeK.png)

I want to display records same page once page filled then it should go to the next page

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zG6TU.png)

Any solution please?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. Do you want to display the records left-to-right on each page or top-down?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.